# How to read all message from queue using stomp library in Python?

Tags: python, stomp

How can I read all messages from stomp queue in Python?

I wrote such code but it reads only one message and exists - how to force read all messages.

```
# coding=utf-8
import stomp
import logging
from medptr.farm.farm import FarmSettings
import platform
import os



if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    class ConnectionListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
        def __init__(self, connection):
            self.connection = connection
            " Current connection. "

        def on_error(self, headers, body):
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            logger.error('Stomp connection error headers = %s and body = %s.' % (headers, body))

        def on_message(self, headers, message):
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            logger.debug('Stomp new message headers = %s and body = %s.' % (headers, message))

    farm = FarmSettings.get_by_hostname()

    conn = stomp.Connection12(host_and_ports=farm.active_mq_settings.hosts_and_ports)
    conn.set_listener('message', ConnectionListener(conn))
    conn.set_listener('print', stomp.PrintingListener())
    conn.set_listener('stats', stomp.StatsListener())
    conn.start()
    conn.connect(username=farm.active_mq_settings.username, passcode=farm.active_mq_settings.passcode, wait=True)
    subscribe_id = '-'.join(map(str, (platform.node(), os.getppid(), os.getpid())))
#         conn.set_listener('stats', stomp.StatsListener())
#         conn.set_listener('print', stomp.PrintingListener())
    conn.send('queue/test', 'hello')
    conn.subscribe(destination='queue/test', id=subscribe_id, ack='client-individual')
    conn.unsubscribe(id=subscribe_id)
    conn.disconnect()
    conn.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TestListner from Stomp Library:

```
conn = stomp.Connection([(host, 61613)]) #This is the default stomp port
listener = TestListener()
conn.set_listener('', listener)
conn.start()
conn.connect(username, password, wait=True)
conn.subscribe(destination=queue_name, id=1, ack='auto')
listener.message_list #This can read all the messages from the queue
headers, message = listener.get_latest_message() #This can read the last message from the queue
conn.unsubscribe(queue_name)
conn.disconnect()
```